# When I try view my jqgrid in IE it appears with a blank space beetween header and table, how to solve this?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jqgrid

See the image below.
How I can solve this problem?

I think that is a css problem, but I am a beginner in css.

[image: Print from my browser(IE9)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 does not support `inline-block`, use `float:left` with `display:block` instead. Don't forget to clear your floats afterward.

Comment: Thanks, I would never find it. But, my grid has a subgrid too.
This solution works for "parent-grid", but the subgrid has the same weird behaviour...

Comment: I guess you'll have to fix the CSS for that too.